# Unique data across browser windows/tabs

Tags: javascript, html, browser

My website has pages served over HTTP and HTTPS. I know that is not recommended due to various reasons, but alas, that's the way things are at this point.

Now, I'd like to be able to store/retrieve data on the client (browser), across pages on my website, in a way that the data is specific/unique across different browser windows/tabs where my website pages may be opened. Therefore, say if I store `myVal` on one tab with value as `1`, then I don't want that to be visible to the other browser windows, which may store its own value of `myVal`.

I've looked into alternatives such as `sessionStorage`, but the biggest limitation with it is the restriction across domains. So, if the same window opens a page served over HTTP and HTTPS, `myVal` wouldn't be accessible on both pages.

Any ideas on how could this be achieved?

Comment: simply stop mixing protocols...

Comment: Agreed, but legacy limits!